# An Issue with the thumbnail image on my Blogger site

Tags: blogger

I have thumbnails that do not appear in their entirety on my site blogger.

[image: blogger-thumbnail]

I tried to add `background-size: cover` and change the dimensions but not conclusive. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: Which ones ? You don't give much info and that link just loads a page without any errors for me... Please update your question to include some details and examples so people don't have to guess!

Comment: The thumbnail of the posts, fair enought ?

Answer (score 0):

Find this line in css :

```
.item-thumbnail .item-thumbnail-resize-landscape
```

then remove these properties :

```
width:1100%;
height:100%;
margin-left:-500%;
```

then find `.item-thumbnail img` and remove properties:

```
max-width: 9999px;
max-height: 9999px;
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad for your answers. Now the thumbnails in the popular post in the right sidebar are not full and when i tried to make it full, they was blurry.

Comment: It's not a popular posts widget it's a Labels widget, images in this widget is cropped badly `/w61/` , and you can't re-crop it since javascript codes is encrypted and there is an interval function to reset it if you tried to manipulate its source.